# Change column names of a cube action as they appear in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, mdx, cube

the title pretty much says it all.
I have a cube with data in it and I have yet to find a way to change the column names.

They appear in a very ugly manner like [cubeName].[$dimension.columnName].
I have tried everything I know and anything I found on the web but nothing seems to be working.

What I tried to do in most cases is create an Action in the Actions tab and write some MDX query language in there. No results whatsoever. As if the action is never run.

Does anyone know how to do this? I've spent about 3 days trying to figure this out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASSP (Analysis Services Stored Procedures) on CodePlex can do this.

http://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Drillthrough

Looks like it may not work well with Excel, due to the multi-selects and the way Excel/SSAS interact. Worth a look though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you cannot edit the cube itself to rename the items? Or even add a virtual dimension (effectively creating a duplicate of each member, but with a different naming standard)? Perhaps create a new virtual cube, which acts as a view on the original cube, but changes the names?